# Updating content with onpopstate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, pushstate

I have a hub that loads pages in to a div with the class 'main', and trying to work out how to be able to go back and forth using browser buttons. I have the following on the settings page:

```
clickHandler(null, null, 'settings');
```

This calls the following:

```
function clickHandler(one,two,three) {
    history.pushState(one, two, three);
}
```

I know that up to this part, it is passing the 'settings' variable as the address bar is showing `/settings` when navigating back. So to try and get settings.php to load in to 'main' I am trying the following:

```
function updateContent(data) {
    if (data == null)
    return;
    console.log(data);
    $(".main").load(data+'.php');   
}

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  console.log("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
  updateContent(document.location)
};
```

However, unless I press back twice really quickly, it's not loading the correct page.

Comment: Why don't you use history.back()?

Comment: @TheKNVB Using history.back() for some reason results in cycling back through all the pages already clicked on.

Comment: @TheKNVB history.back() also returns the value "undefined"